# Не запускается терминал в VSCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, консоль, create-react-app

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Profile from './components/Profile';

const App =()=> {
  return (
   <div className = "app-wrapper">
     <Header/>
     <Navbar />
    <Profile />
   </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```css
.app-wrapper {
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
  'h h'
  'n c';
  grid-template-rows: 60px 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 10fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 1200px;
}
```

Скачала vscode. Вписала в node.js command prompt

npx create-react-appp my-app
cd my-app
npm start

localhost работает, но терминал не запускается.

[попытка запустить код/новый терминал](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GvNr.png)

[output следующий](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyF2J.png)

[скрин всего проекта](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoltI.png)

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1234268/edit))

Comment: попробуйте закрыть все запущенные vscode и открыть снова

Comment: пробовала. ничего не изменилось